# Dynamic snap alignment in Horizontal Pager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-pager

We're attempting to use horizontal pager but, as far as I can tell, the only way to arrange content is through content padding.

For our use case, we want the first item to snap to start, the last item to snap to end, and every other item to snap to center.

I've been able to implement a dynamic content padding based on position but it's SO jerky and results in the creation of a ton of PaddingValues objects.

Is anyone aware of any way to dictate nap alignment?